# How to create a lint warning like "Modifier parameter should be the first optional parameter"?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lint, android-jetpack-compose-modifier

How to create a lint warning like this?

**Lint Warning**
[image: Lint Warning]

I am clear on **Why** this warning is shown and how to fix it.

I am interested in understanding how this lint warning is created and is there a way to make a custom lint warning like this?

Comment: You might see how https://github.com/appKODE/detekt-rules-compose implemented their rules.

Comment: Helpful as always, Mr. Ware. Hey just out of curiosity, if a million people were to simultaneously downvote you for no apparent reason, wouls stack take notice and revert the damage loss?